# How to open a specific viewpager tab on notification click

Tags: objective-c, notifications, navigation, tabbar

I have tab bar on the Main storyboard (not Programmatically), now I want to open specific view controller which is on the 1st tab. this view controller will open when I clicked on Notification. and on click of a back button of this view controller, it will redirect back to the root of that view controller not at home.

Comment: Question is not clear to understand.

Comment: Want to open one view controller which is inside the second tab bar item. from Notification methods in Appdelegate.

Comment: It is Possible. Did you create a viewController class for TabBar?.

Comment: No i created tabbar from Storyboard only.. (sad)

Comment: for each screen(view controller) we need to create a class. Like that create a class for tabbar screen. I mean .h and .m files for tab bar.